# Write my own Find and Replace for Wikipedia in Java

Tags: java

Here is what I tried: https://github.com/curiprogrammer/WikiToLaTeX/tree/master/src

Following text as an example:

```
<!-- Hinweis: Der Artikel [[Konkatenation (Formale Sprache)]] verweist auf diese Überschrift-->
Die '''Konkatenation''' zweier Sprachen <math>L_1</math> und <math>L_2</math> ist die Sprache der Wörter, die durch Hintereinanderschreibung ([[Konkatenation (Wort)|Konkatenation]]) je eines beliebigen Wortes <math>u</math> aus <math>L_1</math> und <math>v</math> aus <math>L_2</math> entsteht:

:<math>L_1 \circ L_2 := \{ uv \mid u \in L_1, v \in L_2 \}</math>.

So sind zum Beispiel die Konkatenationen von verschiedenen Sprachen über dem Alphabet <math>\Sigma = \{ a ,\, b \}</math>:

:<math>\{ a  \} \circ \{ ab \} = \{ aab \}</math>
:<math>\{ a ,\, bb \} \circ \{ aa ,\, b \} = \{ aaa ,\, ab ,\, bbaa ,\, bbb \}</math>
:<math>\{ abb ,\, bab \} \circ \{ \varepsilon ,\, aab ,\, bb \} = \{ abb ,\, bab ,\, abbaab ,\, babaab ,\, abbbb ,\, babbb \}</math>
Heinrich Scholz traf sich 1944 mit [[Konrad Zuse]], der im Zuge seiner Doktorarbeit an seinem [[Plankalkül]] arbeitete. Im März 1945 sprach ihm Scholz für die Anwendung seines Logikkalküls seine Anerkennung aus.<ref>[[Hartmut Petzold]],''Moderne Rechenkünstler. Die Industrialisierung der Rechentechnik in Deutschland.'' München, C.H. Beck Verlag, 1992.</ref>
```

I want to convert the Wikipedia code as seen above into LaTeX code.. For that I need to remove some words like `<!-- SOMETHING SOMETHING -->` or replace others. Example: Replace every : with \begin{equation} + \n and the following  with \end{equation}. But if there is no colon in front of , it should always be $ and  should also be $. Then there is the thing with [[TEXT|text2]] ... it should be converted into text2 on its own.

I have literally no idea how to start this project. There is a .replaceAll() function in Java. But it won't work because I need the mentioned circumstances. Any tips and ideas on how to make this project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you break this into smaller parts. Find the simplest replace rule and try to implement it. Then add the next rule and so on until you finish.

Comment: Hi, here is what I tried so far: https://github.com/curiprogrammer/WikiToLaTeX/tree/master/src

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression for such a situation.

Example: This regular expression can capture text hold by wiki  tags. After captured text, you can use replaceAll method.

```
(:<math>)(.*?)(</math>)
```

Live coding: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RGE6nIwxLtN1F3GY

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Wandbox
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String regex1 = "(<math>)(.*?)(</math>)";
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
        String regex2 = "(:<math>)(.*?)(</math>)";
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);      

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = sc.nextLine();

          // remove html comment tag
          String replaced = line.replaceAll("<!--.*-->", "");

          Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(replaced);
          replaced = m2.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\begin\\{equation}\n$2\n\\\\\\\\end\\{equation\\}\n");

          Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(replaced);
          replaced = m1.replaceAll("\\$$2\\$");

          System.out.println(replaced);
        }
    }
}
```